# Why isn't my code working in C on VS Code?

Tags: c

Pls check it out and help meeee I'm stuck at it since 2+ hours (the "score" variable and other variables that you might see aren't mentioned here because my original code is too long, so I've just listed the important parts of it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  while (1) { //using 1 as a condition since "true" doesn't work

    char* low(char* question) { // a function used for converting the user input into all lowercased
      for (int i = 0; question[i]; i++) {
        question[i] = tolower(question[i]);
      }
    }

    printf("1. Is Python a programming language or a creature? ");
    char question[25];
    scanf("%s", &question);
    low(question);

    if (strcmp(question, "programming language") == 0 || (strcmp(question, "creature") == 0)) {
      printf("Correct! It's both actually 1+ ");
      score += 1;
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Invalid Input ");
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem: It keeps printing out Invalid input even if the answer is correct

Comment: As used `scanf` stops on whitespace, so question will never contain `"programming language".

Comment: C doesn't allow functions declared *within* `main()`. Move the definition of `char * low(char * question)()` above `main()`

Comment: David, I see, but what if I have 5 more functions like that? Will they all go above the main() and I keep creating while loops inside the main()?

Comment: Just keep adding as many as needed outside `main()`. If you want to put them below `main()` that's fine, just put a *declaration* for any function below main above main as well. E.g. *Definition* `char *low (char *question) { ... stuff ... }`  and *Declaration* `char *low (char *question);`

Comment: Suggest `char question[256];` (don't skimp on buffer size) and replace `scanf ("%s", &question);` (note no `'&'` before question -- it's already a pointer) with `fgets (question, sizeof question, stdin);` followed by `question[strcspn(question, "\n")] = 0;` to trim the `'\n'` from the end of input.

Comment: Ohh I get ittt I’m gonna try it out tomorrow morning and let ya know if it works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
scanf("%s", &question);
```

This:

```
scanf("%s", question);
```

Reason: `question` is an array, so when it gets passed as a function parameter, it becomes a pointer to the first element in the array - which is where scanf needs to write to.